# CodeIgniter - template class iterating lists more than once

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

Can't find a solution anywhere. I'm using the template parser class from the CodeIgniter framework and I pass the template a list and use it like such:

```
{categories}
    <li><a href="{id}">{name}</a></li>
{/categories}
```

then later on in the template I use it again.

```
{categories}
    <li><a href="{id}">{name}</a></li>
{/categories}
```

However, it does not work the second time around, the output html is.

```
{categories}
{name}
{/categories}
```

Completely ignoring the syntax, why can you only iterate the list once within the template?

Comment: *Which* template parser class are you using? What do you expect how it should work and why do you expect so?

Comment: The built in template parser class. I expect that I would be able to iterate through list multiple times {list}{/list}, and because thats how smarty does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Template Parser Class is **not** a full-blown template parsing solution. We've kept it very lean on purpose in order to maintain maximum performance. [REF](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html)

Looks like resetting the array prior to iterating over it is not a feature. Feel free to report an issue at the project's homepage.

Comment: Thank you so much. Guess I shall look for a better template solution.

Comment: Or report the issue to the project. I think it's worth that this works as you would like to use it. Should be quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is well over a year old, but I have a solution. The lightweightness of the CI template parser was all I needed for a recent project, but I, too, ran into this problem with the same variable pair occurring multiple times in the same template. I solved it by relying on str_replace()'s ability to replace arrays of strings. Throw the code below into ./application/libraries/MY_Parser.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Overrides the CI Template Parser to allow for multiple occurrences of the
 * same variable pair
 *
 */
class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser {

    /**
     *  Parse a tag pair
     *
     * Parses tag pairs:  {some_tag} string... {/some_tag}
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _parse_pair($variable, $data, $string)
    {
        if (FALSE === ($match = $this->_match_pair($string, $variable)))
        {
            return $string;
        }

        $str = array();

        foreach ($match['0'] as $mkey => $mval)
        {
            $str[$mkey] = '';

            foreach ($data as $row)
            {
                $temp = $match['1'][$mkey];
                foreach ($row as $key => $val)
                {
                    if ( ! is_array($val))
                    {
                        $temp = $this->_parse_single($key, $val, $temp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $temp = $this->_parse_pair($key, $val, $temp);
                    }
                }

                $str[$mkey] .= $temp;
            }
        }

        return str_replace($match['0'], $str, $string);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  Matches a variable pair
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  mixed
     */
    function _match_pair($string, $variable)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match_all("|" . preg_quote($this->l_delim) . $variable . preg_quote($this->r_delim) . "(.+?)". preg_quote($this->l_delim) . '/' . $variable . preg_quote($this->r_delim) . "|s", $string, $match))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return $match;
    }
}
// END Parser Class

/* End of file MY_Parser.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Parser.php */
```